# Google Form to a spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I want to create a Google Form that a teacher can fill out a Discipline Form when sending a student to the office.  That form will them notify the principal that a new form was sent to them and they can view that in the spreadsheet. That will make it MUCH easier for the teachers.  However, the principals will need to print out the answers to each form for the student's files.

So I need to know if I can create a Google Form for teachers to submit but yet allow the principals to print out the form for student records. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

This can be done with the use of Google Apps Script.  You can have code fire off when a form is submitted.  I used the [Tutorial: Simple Mail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/mail_merge) Merge as a starting point.  This allows me to send a custom email to the form responder as well as one to anyone else who needs a message.  You could also generate a PDF for the student's file.  I have seen others who are currently working on the same and are adding functionality for follow-up and resolution reporting.

Another option is to use existing Add-Ons.  These may not give you as much functionality but can be implemented without knowing JavaScript and Google Apps Script, which is JavaScript based.  I have not followed these instructions, but [Get Google Forms Data in an Email Message](https://www.labnol.org/internet/google-docs-email-form/20884/) is an article on using this method.

Comment: I follow a similar workflow for many forms in my district.  A teacher/student/administrator fills out the form, it populates the spreadsheet, an on form submit trigger kicks off some google apps script which generates an email that contains the form responses and sends them to another user to approve/deny using a link in the email.  When they click either the approve or deny buttons in the email it either notifies the person that filled out the form that it was denied or it sends it on for further processing or more approvals until it is finalized. Then it sends an email formatted for printing

Comment: All of this is completely custom, of course, and requires knowledge of Google Apps Script.  That and creation of quite a few work arounds to get around interesting design decisions made by Google.  There are definitely add-ons available for those who are less adventurous that get you most of the way there.